# Implementing Runnable interface in class

Tags: java, multithreading

When the class extends Thread then calling run method by creating class instance.

But for runnable interface we are creating thread instance and passing class instance as argument. After that we are calling run method by thread instance. May i know the algorithm more. Means why can't we call run method by class instance even in implementation class of runnable interface.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide some code to show the problem

Comment: No, we _don't_ ever call `thread.run()`

Answer (score 6):

Technically, you can call the `run()` method of any `Runnable` instance. It just will not run in a seperate thread. That's why you supply the `Runnable` instance to a new instance of `Thread`, and call `start()` on the latter. The JVM will start a new thread and invoke the `run()` method of the `Runnable` instance *on that thread*.

This is also explained in the [Javadoc of class `Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).

Comment: Thank you mthm. I can understand better now by your comment and the following blog.                                                                       http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/what-is-the-difference-between-implementing-runnable-and-extending-thread/29